# Flutter Search bar not displaying all the users

Tags: flutter, dart, search

I have been implementing a search bar in Flutter, which works as expected when searching according to usernames, but does not display all the users when it is empty.

It only displays all the users when typing something in the search bar and completely backspacing it. The following code snippet shows its implementation:

```
class UsersTable extends StatefulWidget {
  List<User> users;
  List<Library> posts;
  UsersTable(
    this.users,
    this.posts, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UsersTable> createState() => _UsersTableState();
}

class _UsersTableState extends State<UsersTable> {
  List<User> _foundUsers = [];

  @override
  initState() {
    // at the beginning, all users are shown
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      _foundUsers = widget.users;
      print(_foundUsers.length);
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  // This function is called whenever the text field changes
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<User> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.trim().isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all users
      results = widget.users;
      print("if filter length");
      print(results.length);
    } else {
      results = widget.users
          .where((user) => user.username
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      // we use the toLowerCase() method to make it case-insensitive
    }
    // Refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      _foundUsers = results;
    });
  }

  Widget body(BuildContext context, List<User> users, List<Library> posts) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Material(
            child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: boxColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          const Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                "Active Users",
                //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none),
              )),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          TextField(
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white38),
                labelText: 'Search',
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                suffixIconColor: Colors.white),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          // SizedBox(
          //width: double.infinity,
          // child: SingleChildScrollView(
          Container(
            child: DataTable(
                columnSpacing: 7,
                columns: const [
                  // DataColumn(
                  //   label: Text(
                  //     "First Name",
                  //     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                  // DataColumn(
                  //   label: Text(
                  //     "Last Name",
                  //     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      "Username",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      "Email ID",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // DataColumn(
                  //   label: Text(
                  //     "DOB",
                  //     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      "Account\nType",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      "Delete\nUser",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text(
                      "View\nPosts",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                rows:
                    //_foundUsers.isNotEmpty?
                    _foundUsers
                        .map(
                          (user) => DataRow(
                            cells: <DataCell>[
                              // DataCell(Text(user.first_name,
                              //     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                              // DataCell(Text(user.last_name,
                              //     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                              DataCell(Text(user.username,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                              DataCell(Text(user.email,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                              // DataCell(Text(user.date_of_birth,
                              //     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                              DataCell(Text(user.account_type,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                              DataCell(
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    primary: Colors.purple,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    // if (user.username
                                    //         .compareTo('hwumazijadmin48') !=
                                    //     0) {
                                    BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context)
                                        .add(DeleteUser(
                                            username: user.username));
                                    // } else {
                                    //   const Text("Cannot Delete Admin");
                                    // }
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('X'),
                                ),
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    primary: Colors.purple,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    List<Library> po = [];
                                    int i = 0;
                                    while (i < posts.length) {
                                      if (posts[i]
                                              .user
                                              .compareTo(user.username) ==
                                          0) {
                                        po.add(posts[i]);
                                      }
                                      i++;
                                    }
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => PostsTable(po),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('\u{1F441}'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList()
                //: []
                ),
          ),
          // ),
        ],
      ),
    )
            //)
            ));
  }
```

Am I missing something in the code?

Comment: can you add a full code snippet?. one more thing you need to trim the search string first as per your comment enteredKeyword.trim().isEmpty then check again

Comment: I have added the full code snippet as required, and implemented your suggestion to use enteredKeyword.trim().isEmpty, but it still does not display all the users.

Answer (score 0):

move `super.initState();` above and remove `Future.delayed`.

```
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _foundUsers = widget.users;        
  }
```

no need to `setState({});` because build method will trigger after `initState`. Also no need for `mounted` because we removed `async`operation.

Comment: This didn't make any difference to the display, and all the users are still not displayed. Thank you for the suggestion though.